# Azure Devops pipeline trigger when a new version of helm chart is published in ACR

Tags: azure, azure-devops

Current my CI pipeline is building, packaging and publishing the artifacts(docker image/helm chart) to ACR.

I want to trigger my CD(continuous delivery) pipeline when either a new helm chart version/ docker image tag is published in the ACR. There are ways to do this for docker image using `resources.containers.container[]`. How can I put another trigger in ADO pipeline to run it when new helm chart version is published?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a workaround:

Step 1. In your build pipeline, you can set a variable as a flag to show whether you have a new helm chart version published. And use it as a condition to set build tag. Here is an example:

```
- script: echo "##vso[build.addbuildtag]HelmChart"
  condition: eq(variables.varName, 'true')
```

Step 2. In your release pipeline, select your build as an artifact. Click on the lightening icon in your stage to set triggers:

[image]

Enable the "Artifact filters". Add your build. Fill in "build tags" with the value you set earlier in the build pipeline.

Then the pipeline will be triggered if a new helm chart version is published.

Comment: I think this refers to classic release pipeline. I'm not using the release pipeline. Just using normal ADO pipeline.